# How can I change the background color of the plot title and caption? [R - ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2

It's my plot.

[image: My plot]

As you see, the color of the plot title and caption background is **white**. I want it black. I tried `panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black")`. As you guess, it changed the color of the panel. Are there any `element_()` functions?

Comment: Try `plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black")`